# pip install pyinstaller in cmd throws an error when trying using the command

Tags: python, cmd

I Have the file first of all. In The website, it says type this into your cmd, pip install pyinstaller I am on windows 10 Hp PC. But, the Cmd says this

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I fix This And succesfully install?

Answer (score 0):

you need to first install pip. this can be done via CMD navigate to your working directory and then use the following command:
**python get-pip.py**.
I hope this solves your issue

Comment: " CMD navigate to your working directory" what does that mean?

Comment: @Jason use cd (change directory) to move to the directory in which get-pip.py is contained and then run the command

Comment: I am young so I do not understand sorry but use cd I do not have a cd disk

Comment: you basically use cd to change the current directory. For example when you open cmd for the first time and you want to navigate to Documents inside cmd you will do "cd Documents". So now you can access all the files in Documents directory through cmd

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added PIP to path. Go to https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ to see more details.